# Help me translate this message

Tags: mathematics, english

I was on my computer last night when, all of a sudden, a message popped up on my screen. The message consisted of nothing more than an image and the following message

> 2024 9251680 2777 763267036

I was able to to determine from the image that the message came from some kind of alien race that had two hands, with 31 fingers on each hand.

Knowing this, can someone help me figure out what this message means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"We come in peace"

> Just convert the numbers to base 62.

Comment: Base 62 is like, say, hexadecimal except that you use 62 different digits.

Comment: Yep, that's the answer. Pretty simple.

Comment: and how did you figured out about the base?

Comment: Telling that the aliens have 62 fingers pretty much tells they use base 62.  And 62 suspiciously equals 10 + 26 + 26, that is 10 digits + uppercase alphabet + lowercase alphabet.